# Find direct parent jQuery

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a html page with 2 datepicker, I have to put the date selected in day/month/year boxes.

My code works fine when I have 1 datepicker, but writes the date always in the first one when having 2

```
<div class="pickergroup">
    <input name="dateDay01" id="dateDay01"> /
    <input name="dateMonth01" id="dateMonth01"> /
    <input name="dateYear01" id="dateYear01">
    <input name="calendario" class="calendario" id="datepicker01">
</div>
<div class="pickergroup">
    <input name="dateDay02" id="dateDay02"> /
    <input name="dateMonth02" id="dateMonth02"> /
    <input name="dateYear02" id="dateYear02">
    <input name="calendario" class="calendario" id="datepicker02">
</div>
```

And the datepicker:

```
    $(function () {
    $(".pickergroup").find('[id^="datepicker"]').datepicker({
        firstDay: 0,
        monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March',
        'April', 'May', 'June',
        'July', 'August', 'September',
        'October', 'November', 'December'
        ],
        dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
        dayNamesShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
        dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            var mycontainer = $(this).parent('.pickergroup');
            var id = $(this).attr('name').substring(10,12);
            var selectedDay = selectedDate.substring(0, 2);
            var selectedMonth = selectedDate.substring(3, 5);
            var selectedYear = selectedDate.substring(6);
            mycontainer.find('#dateDay' + id).val(selectedDay);
            mycontainer.find('#dateMonth' + id).val(selectedMonth);
            mycontainer.find('#dateYear' + id).val(selectedYear);
        }
    });
});
```

How can I choose the correct parent when clicking date02?

Comment: why both have same id "datepicker"?

Comment: Use different `id` for two datepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two date pickers has the same id so the JavaScript code cannot select them. Give each date picker a different ID.

Comment: They still have the same ID - "datepicker01"

Comment: and of course - change the "find" line to the new desired id: find('[id^="datepicker"]') >> find('[id^="datepicker01"]')

Comment: oh yes! it was a mistake updating the post!

Comment: Now fix the "find" to the correct id. Does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

i think you don't need id="datepicker", it's not good if have 2 element with same id. u could try this

```
$(function() {
   $(".pickergroup").find(".calendario").datepicker({
      firstDay: 0,
      monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March',
      'April', 'May', 'June',
      'July', 'August', 'September',
      'October', 'November', 'December'
       ],
       dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
       dayNamesShort: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
       dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
       dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
           var mycontainer = $(this).parent('.pickergroup');
           var selectedDay = selectedDate.substring(0,2);
           var selectedMonth = selectedDate.substring(3,5);
           var selectedYear = selectedDate.substring(6);
           mycontainer.find('[id^="dateDay"]').val(selectedDay);
           mycontainer.find('[id^="dateMonth"]').val(selectedMonth);
           mycontainer.find('[id^="dateYear"]').val(selectedYear);
       }
    });
   });
```